# PromiseKit segmentation fault: 11

Tags: xcode, swift, promisekit

I'm trying to get a basic promise working with PromiseKit. However the following code wont compile:

```
import Foundation
import PromiseKit

class MyClass {
    var myInt: Int?

    func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
        return Promise { fulfill, reject in
            fulfill(1)
        }.then { data -> Int in
            return 3
        }
    }

    init() {
        sample().then { data -> Void in
            debugPrint("got data: \(data)")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
command failed due to signal: segmentation fault: 11
```

This is pretty frustrating. Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: Is the error coming from the Swift compiler, or the program when you run it?

Comment: Its coming from the swift compiler whenever I try to build @kennytm

Comment: If you go to the Report navigator in Xcode (press ⌘8, or click the  on the left panel), you should be able to find the compilation log and find out which line it is causing the compiler to crash.

Comment: Thanks @kennytm. It appears that if I change this line: `}.then { data -> Int in` to `.then { data -> NSNumber in` then it builds fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Int` is not `AnyObject`

```
func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        fulfill(1)
    }.then { data -> Int in
        return 3
    }
}
```

This is most likely fixed in Swift 3, however either of these will fix the compile:

```
func sample() -> Promise<Int> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        fulfill(1)
    }.then { data -> Int in
        return 3
    }
}
```

Or:

```
func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        fulfill(1)
    }.then { data -> NSNumber in
        return 3
    }
}
```